# How do I store my website's config file securely?

Tags: php, security, encryption, config

I have a config.php file for my website that I store outside of the publicly accessible web directory and it contains my password information for a gmail account I use to send mail for the site and my database connection credentials. I don't like the idea of saving the password as a plaintext variable and was looking for some way to have this data more securely saved. Beyond blocking read access to the directory from users other than me, what can I do to secure this information?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to protect against?

Comment: Use the built-in mail sending functions or `sendmail` instead of your gmail. (Actually, for all I know, the built-in mail sending functions use `sendmail`.)

Answer (score 3):

You will end up saving in plain text most of the time. Say for example you want to encrypt, then the key to decrypt will have to saved in plain text etc etc. So better off making sure your server is secure.

Answer (score 1):

Depends from what you are trying to protect.

1. Keeping your file outside the htdocs (webroot directory) is generally a good idea so that the file can't be called explicitly from outside. (I.E directing the browser to it).
2. If you want to protect the $var from within your code (i.e. third party malicious code) you can always unset the variables after they are consumed, although I don't know if that makes much difference.
3. If you want to protect the file from someone that might "hack" into your server, there isn't much you can do. You can always set the file permissions so that only www-data (your apache user) can read it but if someone gains root access to your machine, you are pretty much screwed.

Anyways, if your server is safe (no root access remotely or only through shh with public/private keys, you don't access your server from public PCs, etc...), you don't use third party code without inspecting it first and you store the pass file outside webroot directory, I think you're as safe as you can be.

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much the same conclusion I came too. Thanks for the information!